# Rate of increase of the function

Tags: plane-curves

How do I find the value of the rate of increase of the function $z=x^2+y^2$ along the direction of the given line $y=3x-1$ and in the $xy$ plane at the point $(x, y, z)=(1,2,5)$?

Comment: Try the directional derivative in the direction of the line.

Comment: Your vector is not a unit vector, so you must be wary of this. Put $f(x, y, z)=x^2+y^2-z$ Call $(x, y, z)=(1, 2, 5) = \mathbf{u}$.

Comment: You might want to use the definitions of directional derivative and the gradient.